# Форматирование чисел, из 100 000 000, сделать 100млн

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать форматирование чисел?

Например, если в переменной число **1 000 000**(*миллион*) то выводит **1млн**
Если в переменной число **100 000**(*сто тысяч*), то выводит **100тыс** и т.д.

Ни как не могу найти примеры данного решения, буду рад вашей помощи.

Comment: Напишите свою функцию и не мучайтесь. Если число больше 1млн, делите на 1млн. К получившемуся добавляете млн. Если меньше миллиона, проверяете, на тысячу. Больше тысячи, делите на тысячу и к полученному добавляете тыс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция форматирования чисел к млрд, млн, тыс в общем виде:

```js
/**
 * @param {number} num
 * @return {string}
 */
function formatter(num) {
  if (num > 1000000000) {
    return (num / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' млрд'
  } else if (num > 1000000) {
    return (num / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' млн'
  } else if (num > 1000) {
    return (num / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' тыс'
  }
  return num.toString();
}

console.log(formatter(79894372947239423))
console.log(formatter(79894372947233))
console.log(formatter(7989437294))
console.log(formatter(798943423))
console.log(formatter(79894323))
console.log(formatter(7989423))
console.log(formatter(798423))
console.log(formatter(79823))
console.log(formatter(793))
```

В зависимости от самой задачи, можно не выводить дробную часть. 
Можно реализовать проверку, что если остатка нет, то не показывать 0.